# HOW TO SUM UP IN STRING SET IN PYOMO

Tags: string, sum, set, pyomo

I have a constraint that I called Prod_H2 and it depends on (i,s). This equation have sum of some variables, FIJ (i,j) and FIK (i,k).

```
***i=['U4241', 'U241', 'U241A']
HN_model.i=Set(initialize=[(len(i))])
j=['U4283', 'U283', 'U283A', 'U3283', 'U2280', 'U1280']
HN_model.j=Set(initialize=[(len(j))])
k=['PSA4241', 'PSA241', 'PSA241A', 'PSA3241']
HN_model.k=Set(initialize=[(len(k))])
s=[1]
HN_model.s=Set(initialize=range(len(s)))

HN_model.FIJ=Var(HN_model.i, HN_model.j, HN_model.s,domain=PositiveReals)
HN_model.FIW=Var(HN_model.i, HN_model.s, within=PositiveReals)
HN_model.FIK=Var(HN_model.i, HN_model.k, HN_model.s,within=PositiveReals)***

HN_model.Prod_H2=Constraint(HN_model.i, HN_model.s, expr=sum(HN_model.FIJ[i,j] for j in [len(HN_model.j)]) + sum(HN_model.FIK for k in [len(HN_model.k)]) + HN_model.FIW)
```

I think the error is because the sum is in j, to keep the equation in function i.

DeveloperError: Internal Pyomo implementation error:    'Unknown problem encountered when trying to retrieve index for component FIJ'   Please report this to the Pyomo Developers.

Comment: I think your sets and constraint are not constructed correctly.  Why are you using `len()` everywhere?  Take a look at some of the examples that I have posted with `pyomo` tag for some ideas.  comment back/edit your post if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As @AirSquid said in its comment, you are not constructing correctly the model. First at all, Pyomo allows index to be any datatype, `int`, `float`, `str` or even `datetime`. So, there's no problem to use the actual values of your list `i`, `j`, `k` and `s`. You do not need to use len to construct the set or the constraint index

Now, you got some mistakes in the modelling, besides the previous commented stuff. I'll try to show you:

1. In the constraint modeling, you do not have any equality or inequality sign. In `pyomo` you need whether to use an equality/inequality sign (`==`, `<=` or `>=`) or use other class to model such Equality or Inequality (`pyomo.environ.Expression.inequality(2, model.x)` is equivalent to  `2 <= model.x`)
2. When you're declaring the variables, you're modeling the variables with some index and calling them in the constraint with less index. For example:
   `HN_model.FIJ` is modeled with index `i,j,s` but you're using `i,j` index in the constraint

Finally, I encourage you, as AirSquid told you, to check some examples about how to correctly modeling optimization problems with Pyomo. If you need any help, StackOverflow is always there.

I leave you an example of how to model the problem you just posted

```
from pyomo.environ import *
#set the model
HN_model = ConcreteModel()
i=['U4241', 'U241', 'U241A']
HN_model.i=Set(initialize=i)
j=['U4283', 'U283', 'U283A', 'U3283', 'U2280', 'U1280']
HN_model.j=Set(initialize=j)
k=['PSA4241', 'PSA241', 'PSA241A', 'PSA3241']
HN_model.k=Set(initialize=k)
s=[1]
HN_model.s=Set(initialize=s)

HN_model.FIJ=Var(HN_model.i, HN_model.j, HN_model.s,domain=PositiveReals)
HN_model.FIW=Var(HN_model.i, HN_model.s, within=PositiveReals)
HN_model.FIK=Var(HN_model.i, HN_model.k, HN_model.s,within=PositiveReals)

def constraint(HN_model, i, s):
    '''Constraint modeling. I assume you are using the >='''
    return sum(HN_model.FIJ[i,j,s] for j in HN_model.j) + sum(HN_model.FIK[i,k,s] for k in HN_model.k) + HN_model.FIW[i,s] >= 0
HN_model.Prod_H2=Constraint(HN_model.i, HN_model.s, rule=constraint)
```

Comment: thank you very much!