# How to split parameters in function of define with string?

Tags: python, string, set, expression, pyomo

I need to make an equation (division with PI(i,s) and PJ(j,s)). These parameters have indices.
This code was made in GAMS and here in pyomo the operations with sets (with strings) are different.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

My code:

```
HN_model=ConcreteModel()

i=['U4241', 'U241', 'U241A']
    HN_model.i=Set(initialize=[(len(i))])
    j=['U4283', 'U283', 'U283A', 'U3283', 'U2280', 'U1280']
    HN_model.j=Set(initialize=[(len(j))])
    k=['PSA4241', 'PSA241', 'PSA241A', 'PSA3241']
    HN_model.k=Set(initialize=[(len(k))])
    s=[1]
    HN_model.s=Set(initialize=range(len(s)))

HN_model.ij=Set(within=HN_model.i*HN_model.j, initialize = [(i,j) for i in HN_model.i for j in HN_model.j])

HN_model.T=Param(initialize=300.00)
HN_model.Cp_hidrogenio=Param(initialize=29.00)
HN_model.Cp_metano=Param(initialize=50.00)
HN_model.Cp_medio=Param(initialize=35.00)
HN_model.ef=Param(initialize=0.6)
HN_model.T0=Param(initialize=288.7)
HN_model.P0=Param(initialize=1.00)
HN_model.R=Param(initialize=8.314,)
HN_model.PPi=Param(initialize=5.5)
HN_model.gama=Expression(expr=HN_model.Cp_medio/(HN_model.Cp_medio-HN_model.R))

PJ={}
PJ['U4283',1]=137;
PJ['U283',1]=88.5;
PJ['U283A',1]=88.5;
PJ['U3283',1]=30;
PJ['U2280',1]=30;
PJ['U1280',1]=30;
HN_model.PJ=Param(HN_model.j,HN_model.s,initialize=[PJ])

PI={}
PI['U4241',1]=21.3;
PI['U241',1]=21.1;
PI['U241A',1]=21.1;
HN_model.PI=Param(HN_model.i,HN_model.s,initialize=[PI])

 HN_model.u_power=Expression(HN_model.ij, HN_model.s, expr=(HN_model.T/HN_model.ef)*HN_model.Cp_medio*((HN_model.PJ/HN_model.PI for i,j in HN_model.ij))**((HN_model.gama-1)/HN_model.gama)-1*(HN_model.T/HN_model.T0)*(HN_model.P0/HN_model.PPi))
```

Error:

```
***AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-65250a010a2a> in <module>()
     15 #HN_model.u_power=Var(HN_model.i,HN_model.j, HN_model.s)
     16 
---> 17 HN_model.u_power=Expression(HN_model.ij, HN_model.s, expr=(HN_model.T/HN_model.ef)*HN_model.Cp_medio*((HN_model.PJ/HN_model.PI for i,j in HN_model.ij))**((HN_model.gama-1)/HN_model.gama)-1*(HN_model.T/HN_model.T0)*(HN_model.P0/HN_model.PPi))
     18 HN_model.u_power=Expression(HN_model.i,HN_model.j, HN_model.s, expr=(HN_model.T/HN_model.ef)*HN_model.Cp_medio*((1))**((HN_model.gama-1)/HN_model.gama)-1*(HN_model.T/HN_model.T0)*(HN_model.P0/HN_model.PPi))
     19 HN_model.u_power1=Expression(HN_model.i,HN_model.k, HN_model.s, expr=(HN_model.T/HN_model.ef)*HN_model.Cp_medio*((1))**((HN_model.gama-1)/HN_model.gama)-1*(HN_model.T/HN_model.T0)*(HN_model.P0/HN_model.PPi))

pyomo/core/expr/numvalue.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.NumericValue.__rpow__()

pyomo/core/expr/numeric_expr.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr._generate_other_expression()

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'
```

Comment: Can you please edit the post and show the model and the full ```AttributeError``` ?. Also, your model has the same mistake that in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530394/how-to-sum-up-in-string-set-in-pyomo). Param ```HN_model.PI``` is an ```IndexedParam``` and you're not using the index to call each value

Comment: Ok. Done! I used "HN_model.PI for i,j in HN_model.ij", not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Patricia.

First at all, when you're creating your sets (`HN_model.i, HN_model.j, HN_model.k, HN_model.s`) you're creating a python range based on the length of the array `i, j, k, s`, respectively.
Now, as I reccomend you before, you can use the string list with no problem:

```
i=['U4241', 'U241', 'U241A']
HN_model.i=Set(initialize=i)
```

And this will help you to avoid generating new list and range for data.

Now, for you `AttributeError` is specifically generated by this part:

```
(HN_model.PJ/HN_model.PI for i,j in HN_model.ij)
```

Remember, `HN_model.PJ` is an `IndexedParam`, You can imagine it as a conventional python dict. This means that for calling each element, you need to always pass a key, and the key will depend on the parameterization when creating it. In this case you create it using `HN_model.PJ=Param(HN_model.j,HN_model.s,initialize=[PJ])`. This means that `HN_model.PJ` is a dict-like component, which means it depends on the values of `j` and `s`. If you model sets as i told you above, this means that `HN_model.PJ` got the following index, and the same reasoning applies to `HN_model.PI` param:

```
>>>HN_model.PJ.display()

PJ : Size=6, Index=PJ_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
Key          : Value
('U1280', 1) :    30
('U2280', 1) :    30
 ('U283', 1) :  88.5
('U283A', 1) :  88.5
('U3283', 1) :    30
('U4283', 1) :   137
```

When you use and `IndexedParam`(or `IndexedVar`) you got 2 options: Calling it with an index generating an Expression for each index, or calling it with an index but inside a math function, with generate a single Expression with all indexes. For instance

**An Expression for each index**

`...HN_model.PJ[j,s]/HN_model.PI[i,s])**(HN_model.gama-1)...`

**A single Expression forall indexes**

`...sum(sum(sum(HN_model.PJ[j,s]/HN_model.PI[i,s] for i in HN_model.i)for j in HN_model.j)for s in HN_model.s)...`

The error comes from calling `HN_model.PJ` withouth using any index in an expression.

Then, you can use your model correctly:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
HN_model=ConcreteModel()

i=['U4241', 'U241', 'U241A']
HN_model.i=Set(initialize=i)
j=['U4283', 'U283', 'U283A', 'U3283', 'U2280', 'U1280']
HN_model.j=Set(initialize=j)
k=['PSA4241', 'PSA241', 'PSA241A', 'PSA3241']
HN_model.k=Set(initialize=k)
s=[1]
HN_model.s=Set(initialize=s)

HN_model.ij=Set(within=HN_model.i*HN_model.j, initialize = [(i,j) for i in HN_model.i for j in HN_model.j])

HN_model.T=Param(initialize=300.00)
HN_model.Cp_hidrogenio=Param(initialize=29.00)
HN_model.Cp_metano=Param(initialize=50.00)
HN_model.Cp_medio=Param(initialize=35.00)
HN_model.ef=Param(initialize=0.6)
HN_model.T0=Param(initialize=288.7)
HN_model.P0=Param(initialize=1.00)
HN_model.R=Param(initialize=8.314,)
HN_model.PPi=Param(initialize=5.5)
HN_model.gama=Expression(expr=HN_model.Cp_medio/(HN_model.Cp_medio-HN_model.R))

PJ={}
PJ['U4283',1]=137;
PJ['U283',1]=88.5;
PJ['U283A',1]=88.5;
PJ['U3283',1]=30;
PJ['U2280',1]=30;
PJ['U1280',1]=30;
HN_model.PJ=Param(HN_model.j,HN_model.s,initialize=PJ)

PI={}
PI['U4241',1]=21.3;
PI['U241',1]=21.1;
PI['U241A',1]=21.1;
HN_model.PI=Param(HN_model.i,HN_model.s,initialize=PI)

def u_power(model, i,j,s):
    '''This will generate an Expression in Pyomo for each i,j,s index'''
    return (HN_model.T/HN_model.ef)*HN_model.Cp_medio*(HN_model.PJ[j,s]/HN_model.PI[i,s])**((HN_model.gama-1)/HN_model.gama)-1*(HN_model.T/HN_model.T0)*(HN_model.P0/HN_model.PPi)

HN_model.u_power = Expression(HN_model.i, HN_model.j, HN_model.s, rule=u_power, doc=u_power.__doc__)
```

And when you call `HN_model.u_power.display()` this will give you:

```
u_power : Size=18
    Key                   : Value
     ('U241', 'U1280', 1) :  19025.64990902805
     ('U241', 'U2280', 1) :  19025.64990902805
      ('U241', 'U283', 1) : 24600.466480257248
     ('U241', 'U283A', 1) : 24600.466480257248
     ('U241', 'U3283', 1) :  19025.64990902805
     ('U241', 'U4283', 1) :  27291.28045776289
    ('U241A', 'U1280', 1) :  19025.64990902805
    ('U241A', 'U2280', 1) :  19025.64990902805
     ('U241A', 'U283', 1) : 24600.466480257248
    ('U241A', 'U283A', 1) : 24600.466480257248
    ('U241A', 'U3283', 1) :  19025.64990902805
    ('U241A', 'U4283', 1) :  27291.28045776289
    ('U4241', 'U1280', 1) : 18983.060990494465
    ('U4241', 'U2280', 1) : 18983.060990494465
     ('U4241', 'U283', 1) : 24545.398458397834
    ('U4241', 'U283A', 1) : 24545.398458397834
    ('U4241', 'U3283', 1) : 18983.060990494465
    ('U4241', 'U4283', 1) :  27230.18910845819
```

Since `HN_model.u_power` depends on `i,j,s` index, whenever you're gonna use it, you need to call it with those indexes `HN_model.u_power[i,j,s]`